# How to understand/fix 'Could not resolve all files for configuration' during IntelliJ-gradle plugin build

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

I am just getting started making plugins and am hoping to make an IntelliJ plugin using gradle and java. For now, just to learn the basic, all I am trying to do is change the menubar in IntelliJ. But, following [this IntelliJ tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html), I created a Gradle project with Java and IntelliJ Platform Plugin as the additional libraries/frameworks, and when I build, even if I do not change anything at all once the project is created, I get an error I do not understand and do not know how to fix:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project.project'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not resolve com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:2019.2.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:2019.2.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/2019.2.3/ideaIC-2019.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/2019.2.3/ideaIC-2019.2.3.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

However, when I create a gradle project, and do not use the IntelliJ Platform Plugin, I am able to build and create tasks etc. and as best I can tell it works fine. 
I'm using:
IntelliJ 2019.2.3
Gradle 5.6.2
Java 8

I assume that there is something simple I am missing since I am so new but I haven't seen solutions to this issue elsewhere that I was able to use. Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the errors looks like a problem with the chain of certificates. This happens when the Gradle plugin attempts to download a build of IntelliJ IDEA v2019.2.3. But the Gradle plugin for IntelliJ is not involved when you build a generic project.

Have you tried pasting the URL from the failed `GET` statement into the address bar of your browser?
`www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/2019.2.3/ideaIC-2019.2.3.pom`
Does the POM file download or do you get an error about certificates?

If you get certificate errors, searching for `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` will yield postings about how to [import a server certificate and install it](https://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210) in your JDK's keystore.